Traveling with tools and pc parts
I'll be traveling to Spain soon. I need to take with me a screwdriver and a PSU 1k (pc part)
my question is if a can travel with those things in my luggage in the deposit.

What do you mean with luggage? carry on (that you can access during the flight?) or will it be in the cargohold of the plane?

One of my colleagues had a  screwdriver in his carry-on once and it was confiscated by security. So that will probably need to be checked-in. I think you can have the PSU wherever you want.

@Henriksupportsthecommunity It varies a lot. I had a screwdriver in my carry-on which did CDG-HKG-SYD-HKG before finally getting caught in transit at HKG.


Both are fine in checked luggage
PSU is fine as carry-on as long as it fits inside the size and weight limits for your specific ticket
Screwdriver rules vary greatly from airline to airline and country to country. For example KLM limits them to 6cm, TSA allows up to 7" (which boggles the mind). You need to check with all parties involved in your specific itinerary
Note that if you connect through the US, you WILL have to go through US security (TSA) in both directions
Even if the rules say one thing, it's not uncommon for an agent to do something else. It's typically unwise to argue (if you want to make your flight), so its best to be prepared and go with the flow.
A screwdriver is inexpensive and should be easy to replace in Spain, in case it gets confiscated


actually its the ltt screwdriver. that's why I wanna take it with me it's expensive and also really good. but your answer gives me hope the fly it's a direct one and Colombia - Spain so I should check if there's no problem in spain and I guess I'll be fine
